# Training model using one feature(one column) as label and image as label

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

I am new in data science and i am currently working in a project in witch i have as input a single dataframe(one feature) and the label is a 3D matrix(image). I did not find yet the right model for this tasks. Do you have any idea ?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: You have ony single feature? Do you mean one value for predicting an specific image? Just like ``` if value==1 then result = img1 ``` ?

Comment: Yes I have only single feature shape (513592,1) and the label is an image with shape (444, 637, 4)